# Multi-looping with gitlab Graphql API

Tags: python, graphql, gitlab-api

Im trying to get list of all the pipelines and all the jobs from Gitlab that ran in a day using graphql API, Here is the query I have

```
query = """
    query($projectPath: ID!, $pipelineCursor: String, $jobCursor: String) {
        project(fullPath: $projectPath) {
          pipelines(updatedAfter:"2023-09-06T00:00:00Z",updatedBefore:"2023-09-06T23:59:59Z",status:SUCCESS,first: 100,after: $pipelineCursor,source:"pipeline") {
            pageInfo{
              hasNextPage
              endCursor
            }
            count
            nodes {
              jobs(first: 100, after: $jobCursor) {
                pageInfo {
                  hasNextPage
                  endCursor
                }
                nodes {
                  id
                  status
                  name
                }
              }
              id
              createdAt
              startedAt
              updatedAt
              project {
                id
                webUrl
              }
              ref
              status
              createdAt
              startedAt
              updatedAt
              duration
              queuedDuration
              user {
                username
              }
              configSource

            }
          }
        }
      }
    """
```

```
response = requests.post(
  api_url,
  json={
    "query": query,
    "variables": {
      "projectPath": project_path,
      "pipelineCursor": pipeline_cursor,
      "jobCursor": job_cursor,
    }
  },
  headers=headers
)
```

Im able to get list of all the pipelines but only getting 100 jobs per pipeline. Can anyone please take a look at my query and suggest me what needs to be changed.

**Note**: pipelineCursor loop is working as expected but jobCursor is not looping through all the pages

Answer (score 0):

You have limited jobs to 100 with:

```
jobs(first: 100, after: $jobCursor) {
```

This is a paginated query so you'll have to run it multiple times to get the remaining jobs. Or you could increase the value of `first`.